# Want to show group of year in Cross-browser dateTimePicker Plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using Cross-browser [datetimepicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Cross-browser-Date-Time-Selector-For-jQuery-dateTimePicker/) Plugin in my project. Everything is working fine for me except the showing popup of group of year. When we click on a month, a group of months is shown in it. I want group of the year. when I am click on year. Someone will help me. I am new in jQuery.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35wVG.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I have looked at the plugin, no option. You have to change the base js code of this plugin to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.